# How to open link in new window showing different url on addressbar

Tags: javascript, url

```
window.open(url,"_blank_");
```

I have a sensitive parameter in the url (a password), is it possible to change the shown url on the addressbar in the opened window/tab?

Comment: Remove the ,"_blank" part. Also, don't have a sensative parameter (password) in the querystring.

Comment: You are passing password as GET parameter?

Comment: Even if you could change the shown URL, I can easily set a breakpoint in your JavaScript and view the `url` parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form method="POST" action="url" target="_blank">
    <input type="password" name="password" />
</form>
```

EDIT:

Same, done with javascript:

```
function navigate(url, data, method){
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('method', method);
    form.setAttribute('action', url);

    for(var name in data){
        var hidden = document.createElement('input');
        hidden.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hidden.setAttribute('name', name);
        hidden.setAttribute('value', data[name]);
        form.appendChild(hidden);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form); // Does not need this line in chrome
    form.submit();
}
```

Usage:

```
navigate('url', { password: 'mypassword' }, 'POST');
```

Comment: Also, use HTTPS to post sensitive data; with plain HTTP a password can be easily sniffed.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this syntax. The service I am reaching with the URL is not implemented by me. This what i am trying to reach: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Using+the+Issue+Navigator (Accessing protected data)

Comment: The form has to be appended to document.body:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit
Once you update your answer i accept it.

Comment: @user1977315 it works without appending form to body, I tested it (In chrome only)

Comment: @nagy.zsolt.hun ok, updating

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

refer this document for more information http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Don't recommend w3schools.com. See http://w3fools.com why. Moreover, this doesn't change the shown URL.